# Print to a file using a variable as SQL active record column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, activerecord, printing

Here is my psudocode example:

```
Mydb.find_by_sql("...").each do |data|
.
.
aFile.print(data.time.to_f, " ", data.column_name, "\n")
```

My question is how can I use a variable for the column_name?  I thought something like:

```
aFile.print(data.time.to_f, " ", data.#{column_name}, "\n")
```

or

```
aFile.print(data.time.to_f, " ", data.'#{column_name}', "\n")
```

or

```
aFile.print(data.time.to_f, " ", data."#{column_name}", "\n")
```

but these didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried data.eval "#{column_name}" to no avail...

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
data.send('column_name')
```

So if the ActiveRecord returned has an attribute 'foo'

```
puts(data.foo)
```

is the same as

```
puts(data.send('foo'))
```

UPDATE RE your comment.

```
@x = X.find(1)
['date','age','sex'].each do |attr|
  puts "The value of #{attr} is #{@x.send(attr)}"
end
```

Comment: My column names are stored in an array which is looped through. So, not sure if this would work. Thanks

Comment: @user1499386: What's wrong with `data.send(column_name)`? Did you even try it?